# sum elements (variables) of a vector variable

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, variable

I would like to sum elements of a vector variable, e.g.,
Is

```
xvec = Array[x, 10]
s24 = Sum[xvec[i], {i, 2, 4}]
```

where $s_{24}:=\sum_{i=2}^4 x_i$.
However, I am returned a "Recursion limit". What did I do wrong?[image]

Comment: (1) The error most likely comes from a latent definition.  Try `ClearAll[xvec, x]` and re-executing. Or quit and restart the kernel. (2) Distinguish the syntax for a function call `xvec[i]` from extracting a `Part` `xvec[[i]]`. You want the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Span`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html) to retrieve elements from index 2 to 4. Also note that accessing list elements by indices in Mathematica requires **double** square brackets (see [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)).

```
Total[xvec[[2 ;; 4]]]
(* x2 + x3 + x4 *)
```

Alternatively, you cal also use [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html), but again – mind the double square brackets.

```
Sum[xvec[[i]], {i, 2, 4}]
(* x2 + x3 + x4 *)
```

Comment: Or `s24 = Sum[x[i], {i, 2, 4}]`